# Ajax works only once after success post request

Tags: jquery, ajax

My js file:

```
function getCookie(name) {
  let cookieValue = null;
  if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== "") {
    const cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
      // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
      if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + "=")) {
        cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return cookieValue;
}

$('.cBox').on('click', function(){
    let id_task = $(this).attr('id')
    const data = {
        "id": id_task,
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"payload":data}),
        headers: {
            "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
            "X-CSRFToken": getCookie('csrftoken')
        },
        cache: false,
        success: (data) => {
            if (data.status == 1) {
                $(".tasks-list").load(window.location.pathname + " .tasks-list")
            }
        }
    })
});
```

So, this code listens click on element.
If click was listened - script send AJAX POST request to backend.
If request was successful - backend returns status code 0 or 1.
Then script gets json file from backend and if status code = 1:
script reload div element with class `tasks-list`

But there is a problem.
div reloads only once, further times it's not reloading. How to fix it?

Sorry for my bad knowlegde of Jquery, Ajax
I'm backender, and my frontend knowledge is minimal

Comment: `$(".tasks-list").load(window.location.pathname + " .tasks-list")` will create a `.tasks-list` div nested inside the old `.tasks-list` div. This is probably not what you want. You probably want to replace the div with it, not load into it. This might be related to the problem.

Comment: Is `.cBox` inside `.tasks-list`? If so, you're wiping out any event listeners in that when you reload it. You need to use event delegation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: @Barmar I want to update data in DIV, but how  I understood that my code after ```status:``` isn't corectly

Comment: @Barmar Yes, it's inside ```.tasks-list```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the div instead of loading into it. So the `success:` function should be:

```
        success: (data) => {
            if (data.status == 1) {
                $.get(window.location, function(html) {
                    $(".tasks-list").replaceWith($(html).find(".tasks-list"));
                });
            }
        }
```

You also need to use event delegation for the event handler, since you're replacing the element that you bound the handler to.

```
$("#tasks-container").on("click", ".cBox", function() {
    // rest of your code
});
```

Replace `#tasks-container` with a selector for the containing element that isn't replaced dynamically, e.g. the parent of `.tasks-list`.

See [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: how to specify current url and current html tag in ```get```  like in ```load``` method?  Because ```get``` method doen't see that i specified html tag

Comment: I thought `$.get` allowed document fragments in the URL like `$.load`, but I was wrong. I updated the answer to show how to extract it with `$.get`. But this design seems misguided. You should fix the API so it returns the tasks list directly, instead of requiring you to fetch the whole page again.